# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException when accessing API to preview files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .NET 4.6.1 web service which let's you preview a file and sends it to the browser. I am running a for loop that calls the service for a given number of files. The problem I am having is every alternate call to the service returns Thread was being aborted exception. Meaning that if first call works correctly, the next one will not. The third call will most likely work again and fourth one won't.

How do I fix this error so that every alternate call does not return this exception ?

```
        public void Preview(int fileId)
        {
            // User access to the directory
            CheckDirectoryAccess(GetVvDirectoryId(fileId));
            // Get the CustomerId
            var customerId = GetCustomerId(fileId);
            // Instantiate the required items
            var file = GetVvFileDbObject(fileId);
            var path = GetVvFileServerPath(customerId, fileId);

            var contentType = GetSafeContentType(file["ContentType"].ToString());
            var fileName = GetSafeFileName(file["Name"].ToString());
            // This is not always consistent, just read the file length using the FileInfo
            // var contentLength = file["Size"].ToString();

            // If it's a video, stream it
            if (ShouldStream(contentType))
            {
                StreamMedia(path, contentType);
                return;
            }

            // Clear the response
            _response.Clear();

            // Set the headers
            // Content-Disposition:
            //  serve => inline
            //  download => attachment
            _response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
            _response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
            //_response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);
            _response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
            _response.ContentType = contentType;

            // Check if the file was modified since the last user download
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            // Get the modified date, if not found, created on, if not found, today as the fallback
            var modifiedOn = (file["ModifiedOn"].ParseDate() ?? file["CreatedOn"].ParseDate()) ?? DateTime.Today;

            // Check if the headers contain "If-Modified-Since" header
            if (_request.Headers.AllKeys.ToList().Contains("If-Modified-Since") &&
                _request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"] != null)
            {
                var lastMod = DateTime.ParseExact(_request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"], "R", provider).ToLocalTime();
                // If the file wasn't modified, return 304 Not Modified response to prevent re-downloading
                if (modifiedOn.AddMilliseconds(-modifiedOn.Millisecond) == lastMod)
                {
                    _response.StatusCode = 304;
                    _response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
                    _response.End();
                }
            }

            // Set the cache
            _response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
            _response.Cache.SetLastModified(modifiedOn.ToUniversalTime());

            // Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP 
            // response output stream without buffering it in memory.
            _response.TransmitFile(path);

            _response.Flush();
            _response.End();
        }
```

```
{
    "Message": "Thread was being aborted.",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Threading.ThreadAbortException"
}
```

Comment: Caching `_request` and `_response` is a very odd thing to do. You should probably be disposing them with `using` each time. And this code looks like it could do with a good dose of `async`

Comment: It is legacy code. I thought it could be easy to just reuse it for a quick solution. I might have to rewrite it if it's too much of a pain.

Comment: I still don't understand why alternate API calls receive the error